# How to copy files with certain extensions keeping the path from remote to local machine via scp --parents?

Tags: osx, rsync, scp

I want to copy all *out from various subdirectories from my remote account to my local machine my trail is

```
scp --parents -r  @remote:~/path/*out .
```

this trail doesn't work
I am wondering about the mistake or if there any other alternative way to carry out this job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using rsync,

```
rsync -rav  --include="*out" --include="*/" --exclude="*" user@remote:~/path .
```

exclude everything, but
include all *out files
include subdirectores (needed to recurse)

Comment: it copy every *out file to the ./ directory but  doesn't create the subdirectories

Comment: Are you by change adding a trailing / to user@remote:~/path? With rsync `~/path will copy path and all it's children (with -r), while ~/path/ will only copy it's children.

Comment: For security purposes and to remain congruent with the question, the `-e ssh` option should be added to rsync in order to utilize a secure connection.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `--parents` arg is for cp.  This works for me using a uname and full path:

`scp -r user@remote:/home/user/path/*out .`

Comment: this copy all *out to the same directory, I need to copy and create the subdirectories  also

Comment: Your right, checked again...  The `rsync -r` that's mentioned above would do it.